# Inputting data returned from an Observable in Angular 2

Tags: angular, typescript, observable

So, I'm trying to build an app that will take temperature and humidity data and output those values in the app. As of now I can get the data from my mock data in the data.json and output that data in the HTML template.

However, what I would like to do is take values at a given time and output a different value based on those values i.e. take a Fahrenheit value and calculate Celsius, or calculate the variable pressure deficit(VPD) which outputs a value based on the temperature and humidity.

My hangup is how to get those values in order to plug them into a formula. It outputs using the {{...}} just fine, but I haven't a clue how to add/subtract/divide etc. those values.

Service:

```
  getData(): Observable<TempRh[]> {
   return this._http.get('./assets/data.json')
  .map((response: Response) => response.json())
  .do(data => console.log("All: " + JSON.stringify(data)))
  .catch(this.handleError);}
```

Component:

```
  ngOnInit(): any {
    this._dataService.getData()
    .subscribe(
    tempHum => this.tempHum = tempHum,
  );}
```

Template:

```
  <ul>
    <li *ngFor="let tempHum of tempHum">{{tempHum.temperature}} , 
    {{tempHum.humidity}}</li></ul>
```

Data:

```
[
{"date": "2012-05-01", "temperature": 70, "humidity": 70},
{"date": "2012-05-02", "temperature": 74, "humidity": 72},
{"date": "2012-05-03", "temperature": 79, "humidity": 65},
...]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this.Inside your component you can declare a function and a new array:

```
modifiedTempHum: Array<any>;

private transformTemp(tempHum) {
  for (let item of tempHum) {
    const temperature = item.temperature;
    const humidity = item.humidity;

    // here you do what you want with your variables

    modifiedTempHum.push({ Temperature: temperature, Humidity: humidity });
    }
}
```

Then you bind the modified array to your html:

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let tempHum of modifiedTempHum">{{tempHum.Temperature}} , 
    {{tempHum.Humidity}}</li></ul>
```

And you call your function on ngOnInit():

```
ngOnInit(): any {
    this._dataService.getData()
    .subscribe(
    tempHum => this.transformTemp(tempHum),
  );}
```

Comment: Thanks this definitively helped. I can get the result of the calculation I want to print to the console, but I'm having trouble pushing the results to the empty array. The new data isn't getting outputted in the HTML. `code>>>> calculateVpd(tempHum) {
  for (let item of tempHum){
    const temperature = item.temperature;
    const humidity = item.humidity;
    const celsius = (temperature - 32) / 1.8;
    const variablePressure = (100 - humidity) * 2486;
    this.VPD.push(variablePressure);
    console.log(variablePressure);
  }`

Comment: `code <ul>
    <h6>VPD</h6>
    <li *ngFor="let VPD of VPD">VPD: {{ vpd?.variablePressure}}</li>
  </ul> `

Comment: That's because you are not pushing objects like in the example I give, instead your array has only numbers, which are your variablePressure. This should work `<ul> <h6>VPD</h6> <li *ngFor="let vpd of vpd">VPD: {{ vpd }}</li> </ul>`. Just a side note, avoid using the same name for the iterator and collection you iterate on.

Comment: I think I follow what you're saying but I still get a <ul> the length of the array, but no values get outputted i.e. "VPD: <no value here> ".

Comment: Just make sure you push like you described before `this.VPD.push(variablePressure);` and your collection has the values. It worked for me without problems.